# Confused by accessing the object property with dot or square brackets

Tags: javascript, properties, square-bracket

Going through some online resource I've came across these examples:

In this case **this** properties can be accessed via `this.property` method and `this['property']`, but can't be accesed using `this[property]`

```
function showFullName() {
  alert( this.firstName + " " + this.lastName );
}

var user = {
  firstName: "Alex",
  lastName: "Graves"
};

showFullName.call(user)
```

In the following example accessing the properties using `this.property` and `this['property']` leads to `undefined`.

```
var user = {
  firstName: "Alex",
  surname: "Graves",
  secondSurname: "Martinez"
};

function showFullName(firstPart, lastPart) {
  alert( this[firstPart] + " " + this[lastPart] );
}

showFullName.call(user, 'firstName', 'secondSurname')
```

Can you please clarify a bit the behavior of dot and square brackets?

Comment: The second example works, or are you expecting anything else?

Comment: @LeonAdler I do apologize for the confusion, I did expect some explanations or maybe some external resources about the difference and behavior of accessing the properties of objects.

Comment: The only difference is that string literals, as used in brackets, can contain characters that a property written using dot notation can't contain, otherwise they are basically the same.